UK Masters Application: UG Exams missed due to illness: concerned about low degree grade percentage despite first class
I recently finished my undergraduate degree in the UK and am now applying for master’s programs. I performed pretty well in my degree and was expecting a first. Unfortunately, I missed two of my final exams due to illness. My tutor told me I’d likely need to retake them in August, but the university ultimately decided to award me a first-class degree without requiring the retakes. They also gave me a departmental prize.
While I'm obviously pretty pleased about that, the problem is that, in terms of masters applications, while my degree classification is a first, my percentage grade is around 63 because of the missed exams being 0. Some of the master’s programs I’m applying to are pretty competitive, so I’m worried that the lack of a high percentage grade might hurt my chances.
Any advice on how to handle this? Should I email admissions teams to explain the situation? If so, would it help to provide the grade with the affected modules excluded?

Your situation is going to be confusing to anyone familiar with the UK system. The standard rule is that a "first class degree" means an overall average mark of 70% or higher. If you are unable to sit summer exams due to illness the usual procedure is that you provide some sort of medical evidence and are allowed to retake them later in the summer.
Since your university is doing something unusual you should make certain that one of your academic referees explains it prominently in their reference letter.  That's the easiest way to get the information to the people making admissions decisions.  You can email the admissions team but it's likely they don't have a way of adding the content of your email to your application.  It won't be helpful to provide a grade with the affected modules excluded because that's not the grade you have.

it's not a good idea to accept this answer straight away - others may have better advice and be put off answering.  You can the green tick to unaccept.

It’s actually to the OPs advantage that their transcripts show zeros, this is an additional sign that this wasn’t a typical bad grade without extenuating circumstances (as might be the case for a 30 or 40 mark), and should mean anyone reviewing it is primed to look for additional information in references, cover letters or personal statements.

It's not THAT unusual.  Cambridge has always awarded degrees DDH (deemed to have deserved honors) in cases of missed exams.
